# how to solve multiple http request in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

problem

- on 1 http request 3 or more http request is working i don"t know why.
- though above code is working to kill remaining request , but i need to why browser is making multiple call for same request.

js code

```
var sbAdmin2 = angular.module('sbAdmin2',[]);


sbAdmin2.controller('countCtrl', function($scope,$http,$q){

 var canceler = $q.defer();
 var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://cors.io/?u=https://api.github.com/',
        timeout: canceler.promise,
        headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
},

    }).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log("data");
        $scope.res=data.data[0].to_client;
        $scope.res1=data.data[0].open_logs;
          $scope.res2=data.data[0].to_mtl;



    });

     setTimeout(function () {

            canceler.resolve();
        },600 );
  // canceler.resolve("user cancelled");

  });
 });
```

html code

```
 <div ng-controller="countCtrl">
 </div>
```

- i have tried differ and timeout in angular js to cancell remaining xhr calls that works but im not able to generate issue why browser is making multiple round strips for single request.
- like

  ```
    url 200 ok 

    url 200 ok

    url 200 ok
  ```
- i need for one request it should produce only url 200ok only
- any help is most welcome
- browser google chrome
- on debugging countrl controller is calling 3 times that why its making 3 times call

Comment: Can you reformat the code? is 'setTimeout' inside of your http request?

Comment: Is it by any chance possible that you are using this controller on more than one element?

Comment: Why are you using a setTimeout to resolve the promise? Is this just for testing? I'd remove that for starters...

Comment: kazimeries you are right